# Android: Add two TextViews to Actionbar Spinner

Tags: android, textview, android-actionbar, spinner

Is there anyway to add two text views or strings inside of the Actionbar Spinner?

Similar to how the Android GMAIL app does it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class spinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public spinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_text_layout, null);
                holder.text1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText1);
                holder.text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText2);
                convertView.setTag(R.layout.spinner_text_layout, holder);
            } else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(R.layout.spinner_text_layout);
            }

            holder.text1.setText("Position: " );
            holder.text2.setText(position);

            return convertView;
            }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder2 holder;

            if(convertView == null){
                holder = new ViewHolder2();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_text_layout, null);
                holder.text1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText1);
                holder.text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText2);
                convertView.setTag(R.layout.spinner_text_layout, holder);
            } else{
                holder = (ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag(R.layout.spinner_text_layout);
            }

            holder.text1.setText("Position: " );
            holder.text2.setText(position);

            return convertView;
            }

        static class ViewHolder{
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
        }

        static class ViewHolder2{
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
        }

    }
```

spinner_text_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: The solution provided by user1888162 is correct. You need to create your own custom adapter and provide it with a custom row layout which contains two text views. If you need further this might be of some help http://dandar3.blogspot.in/2013/03/actionbarsherlock-custom-list-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

[`ActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setListNavigationCallbacks%28android.widget.SpinnerAdapter,%20android.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener%29)

It's just a `SpinnerAdapter`. If you are familiar with adapters, you can make your own class extending `BaseAdapter` and have a custom layout. If you aren't familiar with adapters, I suggest you watch [The World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).