# Is there any way to show custom row in actionbar navigation mode list, but not in dropdown menu?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, navigation, android-actionbar, custom-adapter

I'm using ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and I have a custom adapter for the Spinner

**Here is a Screen shot!**[Each row in drop down consists of two text Views.]

[image]

My problem is that i only want to show both the text views in the actionbar only not in the drop down list.

**My Required Layout is like this:**
[image]

Please Help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176763/android-add-two-textviews-to-actionbar-spinner